# Can't install Microsoft OneNote for PC

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-onenote

I'm trying to install OneNote on PC (Win8.1). Downloaded and installed the file
setuponenotefreeretail.x86.en-us_.exe.
All is fine except when I exit program it is nowhere to be found on my machine.
What's going on??

Comment: The type of installer and your OS are both 32 bit? or 64 bit?. A mismatch could also cause such a problem. See if there is an entry under the program files folder

Comment: Please provide some information:  what is setup...., where did you download it from, what error messages can you find?

Answer (score -1):

As part of Microsoft Office 2013, the shortcut to your OneNote should be found under the folder: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office 2013.

The real executable may be found here : "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\onenote.exe"

Nevertheless, with a proper installation, you should find a shortcut when pressing the "Windows key" of your keyboard, then by accessing the apps thanks to the arrow in the bottom left hand corner.
It should also show up in the search list on the right, by pressing the "Windows Key", then typing "OneNote".

Comment: Thank you very mcuh for your help Michael, Prasanna & Marius.

Comment: Thank you very mcuh for your help Michael, Prasanna & Marius. I have found the executable following your directions Michael. I am on a 64-bit machine, so was looking in the (x86) program folder (which is what the setup file would suggest). Strange that there is no program folder in the Start menu, no shortcut. Search  now finds it when it did not before. Have put shortcut on desktop which is fine. Thank you very much!